The light on my ceiling fan shuts off every 2 minutes and 47 seconds. NOT the ceiling fan, JUST the light
I have an older concord remote control that works with my ceiling fan and light.  The light shuts off automatically every 2 minutes and 47 seconds.  Then I push the button on the remote to turn the light back on and after 2 minutes and 47 seconds, it shuts off AGAIN.  This happens over and over again.  It's like it's on a timer or something.  How can I get this to stop shutting off???

What's the wattage rating of the receiver and what's the wattage rating of the bulbs you have in your fan? I'm wondering if the receiver has some sort of built in power limiter...also, if you turn it on and then do nothing, does it keep cycling on and off or just turn off and not ever come back on until you turn it on at the remote again?

change the battery on the remote

Check the manual. Maybe the fan has a timer feature that you accidentally activated.

Indeed, power limiters are a common/normal/standard item in fan lighting, so overlamping seems like the most likely issue here.

I'd try the light bulb in another location.  It could be overheating and shutting itself off

What is the make and model of fan? Is the remote control an add-on? Does the lamp have PIR sensing, looking for movement?
